# codeigniter input post method returns empty array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a data-entry,with controller which inputs the data, displays it and confirm for any edit then uses a method to submit it to the model.

The problem is that in the load the model in the `function post_data()` the value of `$this->input->post()` return an empty array.

I am entering the data returning to the get_data function and then displaying it in the data.php in the view.
using

**data.php** in view post the data to the post_data method.

```
<form id='form'  action="<?php echo base_url("welcome/post_data"); ?>" method="POST" style="display:inline;">           
<input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php echo $this->input->post("xyz") ?>" />
```

the controller is

```
protected $arr;
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('index/index');
    // $this->load->library('Controllerlist');
    // print_r($this->controllerlist->getControllers());
}
public function get_data(){
    echo "matoercod";
    $this->load->view("index/data");        
}
public function post_data(){
$this->load->model("form1","form",TRUE);
 print_r($this->input->post());
    $blue=$this->form->insert_data($this->arr);
    print_r($blue);
    if($blue){
     echo "Successfully added to database"; 
    }
}}
```

Why does print_r() method return an empty array?
$this->input->post() in the post_data method return empty array.
if Iam right  $this->input->post() should is global to all the method in Controller CI class.

Comment: Kindly clarify which $this->input->post() is not working.

Comment: the one in the post_data method.

Comment: Are you sure, that $this->input->post("xyz") has a value? Have you tried to just set a fixed value?

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` tag in `form` doesn't have a `name` attribute.

```
<form id='form'  action="<?php echo base_url("welcome/post_data"); ?>" method="POST" style="display:inline;">           
    <input name="xyz" type="text" value="<? php echo $this->input->post("xyz") ?>" />
</form>
```

**Edit:**
Also the `input` tag is closed in a wrong way (closing before the `value` attribute).

```
<input type="text name="xyz" value="<? php echo $this->input->post("xyz") ?>" />
```

Comment: Iam really sorry that was a typo.

Comment: guess noobness never ends.

Comment: Did it helped ? What was the issue ?

Comment: nope,still stuck seems like the $_POST values are being lost,in the scope of post_data

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the view **data.php** in **get_data**:

```
public function get_data(){
    echo "matoercod";
    $this->load->view("index/data");        
}
```

Then how are you accessing the get_data url? If you are just typing it in the browser, then you are not POSTing you are GETing and so $this->input->post is *always* going to be an empty array.

It's not entirely clear to me how you are calling your method get_data, but you should probably try to alter it so that it more carefully constructs the data you want to be displayed in any view that it loads

```
public function get_data(){
    $view_data = array(
        "xyz" => "here is some value" // you could get this value from anywhere
    );
    $this->load->view("index/data", $view_data);
}
```

Then in your view **data.php** you would want to refer to just $xyz instead of $this->input->post("xyz"):

```
<form id='form'  action="<?php echo base_url("welcome/post_data"); ?>" method="POST" style="display:inline;">           
<input type="text" name="xyz" value="<?php echo $xyz; ?>" />
```

Note that second parameter to the view loading function. It's an array and each associative key in the array will be expanded into a variable within your view.